# Cakephp 2 session duration

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I've got a problem with a session duration in Cakephp 2. I set up my Config/core.php file according to the Cakephp documentation:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'cookie' => 'suser',
        'timeout' => 2160, // 36 hours
        'ini' => array(
            'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 129600 // 36 hours
        ),
        'cookieTimeout' => 2160,
        'autoRegenerate' => true
    ));
```

And it doesn't work - all the sessions expire after about 3 hours. I'd like to extend their duration. Is there anyone able to help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to false 'autoRegenerate' => false

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help. All the sessions expire after few hours. Do you have any other ideas maybe?